# How to prevent the user from clicking on tabs - visual basic

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol

[TabControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F1es.png)

I am trying to create a quiz with tabs for each question. I want to prevent the user from clicking the above tabs to navigate and instead can only press the next button which moves onto the next tab.

I tried setting the enabled as false and then setting enabled as true inside the next button but that does not seem to work.

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        TabControl1.SelectTab(1) 
    End Sub
```

This is the piece of code which moves onto the next tab. This works fine when enabled is set to true

Comment: You can't use the Enabled property since that stops the user from clicking the Next button.  And more severely, from answering the question.  Use the Selecting event instead, set e.Cancel = True if you don't like where the user wants to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. where would I find the selecting event? sorry I'm new to coding

Comment: Would I need to add e.cancel inside an if statement?

Comment: You can always check the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol?view=windowsdesktop-5.0  Here you can find all the properties, methods and events. Click on the Selecting event to see more about it.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selecting?view=windowsdesktop-5.0